# How would I write this script to create a file with small differences?

Tags: batch-file, hex, command-prompt

I'm trying to write a simple .bat script that will help me create some files I need for testing at my work. Basically these files are about 15,000 lines that all contain a bunch of hex values. What i would need is the file to find a specific value and change it slightly. I need it to find and change the byte address 0x80020304 by adding 1 to it, and then subtracting one from the end of that line.

So for example it would find that byte address, and this little snippet of the code

> S325800202E0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000076
>   S3258002030000000000D78B21E608000000000202801B020280000802801F4F02800000038044
>   S32580020320FFFF038000000480FFFF048000000580FFFF0580000006801F4F06800000078015

Would turn into this

> S325800202E0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000076
>   S3258002030000000000D88B21E608000000000202801B020280000802801F4F02800000038043
>   S32580020320FFFF038000000480FFFF048000000580FFFF0580000006801F4F06800000078015

Remember that in hex, each byte address is 2 characters. So you add 1 to the D7 and it becomes D8 and at the end of the line the 44 subtracts one and becomes an 43. If the number at the end were to be 40, It would have to turn into 3F.

I do not have even the slightest clue of how to do this. All i really know is how to set the input and output files, but when it comes to manipulating the output file, I'm not very knowledgeable. Also I'm not sure how it will change since I am working with hex.

Thank you all in advance for any help you may provide. It is very much appreciated.

Comment: Swiss File Knife has these options if it helps in this way: `make-random-file - create file with random data` and this one `fuzz       - change file at random, for testing`

Comment: No I don't think it will help, they have to be very specific changes to these data files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
set /p "infile=Filename?"
(
FOR /f "usebackqtokens=1*delims=" %%a IN ("%infile%") DO (
  if defined infile (CALL :process %%a
  ) else (echo(%%a)
)
)>newfile.txt

GOTO :EOF

:process
SET line=%1
IF NOT %line:~0,12%==S32580020300 ECHO %line%&GOTO :EOF
set "infile="
:: Increment nybble 21 (count starts at 0)
CALL :inc %line:~21,1%
:: build byte
SET b1=%line:~20,1%%rep%
:: if replacement was 0, then increment was F->0, so incr. prev. nybble
IF %rep%==0 (CALL :inc %line:~20,1%) ELSE (GOTO decb2)
SET b1=%rep%%b1:~-1%
:decb2

:: Repeat above, but decrement on last 2 nybbles.

CALL :dec %line:~-1%
:: build byte
SET b2=%line:~-2,1%%rep%
:: if replacement was F, then decrement was 0->F, so decr. prev. nybble
IF %rep%==F (CALL :dec %line:~-2,1%) ELSE (GOTO rebuild)
SET b2=%rep%%b2:~-1%
:rebuild
SET line=%line:~0,20%%b1%%line:~22,-2%%b2%
ECHO %line%

GOTO :eof

:inc
SET rep=0
FOR %%a IN (F E D C B A 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0) DO IF %%a==%1 (GOTO :eof) ELSE (SET rep=%%a)
:dec
SET rep=F
FOR %%a IN (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D E F) DO IF %%a==%1 (GOTO :eof) ELSE (SET rep=%%a)
```

I used a file named `q23015544.txt` containing your data for my testing.
Produces newfile.txt

Substrings in batch are obtained from `%var:~m,n%` where `,n` is optional; `m` is count-of-chars-from-beginning-of-string, from end if negative. `,n` positive = max length to return; negative = end-position in chars from end; missing=return all after `m`

So, the batch looks first for the target line - it begins with the 12-character string indicated. Any other line, it simply spits back out. For the target line, it selects the least-significant nybble and calls a routine to either increment or decrement that nybble, and repeats the operation if ther was a carry-over (detected by the replacement character in `rep` becoming `0` for increment or `F` for decrement)

Then simply a matter of rebuilding the line and outputting it.

The structure

```
(commands...)>file
```

causes any data `echoed` to appear in a newly-created file - even if the `echo` appear in a called subroutine.

---

I've edited the batch to tackle the speed problem and allow the filename to be input, but I've not tested the changes.

You could use the `set /p...` to input a filename or

```
set "infile=%~1"
```

to accept the filename as a batch parameter (ie. an argument to the batch file)

The other change is to clear the value of 'infile' when the target line is detected. Batch will already know which file to read, and the absence of `infile` in the environment is then detected in the loop, so the raw line will be output - it won't call the subroutine at all. That should speed it up considerably.

---

Stream! the magic word...

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "infile=Filename?"
SET "line="
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a IN ("%infile%") DO CALL :process %%a&IF DEFINED line GOTO nextstep
ECHO Target NOT found&GOTO :eof
:nextstep
sed s/%original%/%line%/g "%infile%" >newfile.txt

GOTO :EOF

:process
SET original=%1
IF NOT %original:~0,12%==S32580020300 GOTO :EOF
SET line=%1
:: Increment nybble 21 (count starts at 0)
CALL :inc %line:~21,1%
:: build byte
SET b1=%line:~20,1%%rep%
:: if replacement was 0, then increment was F->0, so incr. prev. nybble
IF %rep%==0 (CALL :inc %line:~20,1%) ELSE (GOTO decb2)
SET b1=%rep%%b1:~-1%
:decb2

:: Repeat above, but decrement on last 2 nybbles.

CALL :dec %line:~-1%
:: build byte
SET b2=%line:~-2,1%%rep%
:: if replacement was F, then decrement was 0->F, so decr. prev. nybble
IF %rep%==F (CALL :dec %line:~-2,1%) ELSE (GOTO rebuild)
SET b2=%rep%%b2:~-1%
:rebuild
SET line=%line:~0,20%%b1%%line:~22,-2%%b2%

GOTO :eof

:inc
SET rep=0
FOR %%a IN (F E D C B A 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0) DO IF %%a==%1 (GOTO :eof) ELSE (SET rep=%%a)
:dec
SET rep=F
FOR %%a IN (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D E F) DO IF %%a==%1 (GOTO :eof) ELSE (SET rep=%%a)
```

This version should be heaps faster, but it relies on `SED` which is a third-party product. I use GNUSED - Google is your friend.

Comment: This is exactly what I need, anyway I can have the it choose the input file? I think it would be something like this right? 
@SET input_file=%1

Comment: Also, After it finds the correct line and runs the process, does it then still check the rest of the lines? Because it takes so long to finish each file. That bit of code always comes early on in the file. Would it be faster to analyze only the first 100 lines, and then merge the two files?

Comment: I think I see what you did there. What the code now does is it outputs everything before that line. I still need it to output the changed line, and then everything after that as well. I just don't need to keep checking for the line to change anymore, because then we are done with changing the line. I just need it to output everything after that? Does that make sense or am I being confusing haha

Comment: I think if we set the input file to undefined, it doesn't have anywhere to pull data from...

Comment: Actually, I was wrong(no surprise). It does work perfectly now. Thank you soo much for all your help!!

Comment: Would it maybe be faster to do some sort of stream instead of echo for each line after that?

Comment: I wish I could give you more points for this. First test was 10 mins, You helped me shorten that time to 1.5 minutes. Now it is about 10 seconds. This is awesome and very helpful. I just wish I can learn enough to help others in the future. Thank you once again!